# Having a nullable property of my model showed in my create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, razor

I use EntityFramework CodeFirst MVC3. In my model I defined a nullable property like this:

```
public class PostFullViewModel
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    ...
    public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here is my Create action controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PostCreateViewModel viewModel = new PostCreateViewModel
        {
            PostToCreate = new PostFullViewModel(),
            Authors = m_AccountBusiness.GetAllUsers().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.UserName, Value = x.UserID.ToString() })
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

In my create view:

```
@model PostCreateViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostToCreate.PublishDate)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostToCreate.PublishDate)
    ...
}
```

I got an error on the EditorFor line:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.
```

How can I proceed to have my creation view showing the PublishDate empty?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is PostToCreate property from? can you elaborate more?

Comment: I updated my question to show the create action controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you defined a custom editor template for the DateTime type (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml` or `~/Views/XXX/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml` where `XXX` is your current controller name) which is strongly typed to `DateTime` instead of `DateTime?` like this:

```
@model DateTime
...
```

So you could change its type to `DateTime?`.

Comment: Thanks. I updated like you show me with DateTime? and in the code of my editor template I test if Model.HasValue to show the date formatted in the textbox or to show an empty textbox if null.

Comment: @Bronzato, you don't even need a custom editor template if all you need is format the date using some custom format. You could simply decorate your `PublishDate` property with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute, just like that: `[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "", DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess either as Darin, BTW when I assume PostCreateViewModel class as below, I did not have any problem in create view

```
public class PostCreateViewModel
    {
        public PostFullViewModel PostToCreate { get; set; }

    }
```